# How to handle live data of Accelerometer in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, accelerometer, android-sensors

I need to perform Dynamic Time Wrapping(DTW) algorithm with some previously stored data and Accelerometer data. But I am unable to handle the huge amount of data coming from accelerometer. I need to determine a step. In order to do that I have stored a number of data previously and trying to match with the current data.

```
ArrayList<Double> test=new ArrayList<Double>();

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
   double x=event.value[0];
   double y=event.value[1];
   double z=event.value[2];

   double a=Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z);
   test.add(a);
   new ProgressRunner().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,x);

private class ProgressRunner extends AsyncTask<Double, Integer, Boolean>
{
   @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Double... params) {
       new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

        double r=DTWDistance(StepSamples.sample1, standTest);
        if(r<700) /* "Step Detected */
            }
        }).start();
        return null;
    }
```

But I am getting huge data coming from the sensor. My question is how do I handle this data and match with a sample data continuously. Also I have tested with a Log.d, I'm sure the problem is related to how I handle this Live data but I can't find a way out. Any suggestion would be helpful.
I have also tried this by doing it an interval of 2 sec but an OutOfMemeoryBoundsException throws

```
if((System.currentTimeMillis()-sTime)/1000>2){
        new ProgressRunner().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,x);
    }
```

Comment: ur program will create too many threads because a huge amount of data will be coming up from the sensors

Comment: I know,..what you suggest.

Comment: Many apps are out there which handles this live data coming from sensors.. there must be some way to handle it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solution to address this problem is keeping a threshold for the change in the sensor values. If the change in `deltaX`, `deltaY`, `deltaZ` are greater then you can start the AsyncTask else dont.

Since u are not keeping any threshold values the number of threads u create is very huge in number.

**EDIT 1:**

Here is a link to a small tutorial that will help you to kick start... in this link he has used a time interval and a threshold for shaking the device... i bet this is a perfect solution for your requirement

[Tutorial Link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-accelerometer-on-android--mobile-22125)

Comment: check my edit... mark this answer solved if it solved ur query so that it might help others.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to process every single value or are you fine processing every x (e.g. 0.1) seconds? I call a method that checks "now - lastProcessedTime". If that value is > 100ms, I will handle the data and update lastProcessedTime = now. If not, I will throw away the sensor value.